# Adding HSTS headers in app.yaml (Google App Engine)

Tags: google-app-engine, https, http-headers, app.yaml, hsts

I have the following handlers section in my `app.yaml`:

```
handlers:
  - url: /(robots\.txt|sitemap\.xml)
    static_files: \1
    upload: (robots\.txt|sitemap\.xml)
    secure: always
    http_headers:
      Strict-Transport-Security: 'max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains; preload'
  - url: /.*
    script: main.app
    secure: always
    http_headers:
      Strict-Transport-Security: 'max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains; preload'
```

and another subdomain, served by the another submodule (`static.yaml`) has the following:

```
handlers:
  - url: /
    static_dir: files
    secure: always
    http_headers:
      Access-Control-Allow-Origin: '*'
      Strict-Transport-Security: 'max-age=63072000; preload'
```

I was able to deploy `static.yaml` without any issues to the appengine:

```
$ appcfg.py update static.yaml
12:48 PM Host: appengine.google.com
12:48 PM Application: XXXXXX; module: static; version: 1
12:48 PM
Starting update of app: XXXXXXXX, module: static, version: 1
12:48 PM Getting current resource limits.
12:48 PM Scanning files on local disk.
[...]
[...]
12:49 PM Checking if updated app version is serving.
12:49 PM Completed update of app: XXXXXX, module: static, version: 1
```

whereas, when I try to update the `app.yaml` configuration, I get:

```
$ appcfg.py update app.yaml
12:48 PM Host: appengine.google.com
Usage: appcfg.py [options] update <directory> | [file, ...]

appcfg.py: error: Error parsing .\app.yaml: Unexpected attribute "http_headers" for mapping type script.
  in ".\app.yaml", line 31, column 1.
```

I understand that it means I'd have to handle HSTS configuration in my python script itself. But, I have ~10 handlers in the `main.app` interface. Instead of updating each of those to add the STS header, is there some alternative to do so at `app.yaml` level itself?

Checking the [`app.yaml` reference on GAE](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appref), there is no mention of restriction of `http_header` directive in `script` type mapping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the doc:
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/using-custom-domains-and-ssl

*You cannot use Strict-Transport-Security headers unless your domain is whitelisted. To place your domain in the whitelist, contact ...*

**UPDATE**

As of 2018, custom domains don't need to be whitelisted. In other words, HSTS headers are not stripped out anymore.

Comment: I think this is out of date.  That doc no longer mentions a whitelist.

Comment: The mention is still there, the link has changed: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/securing-custom-domains-with-ssl

Answer (score 5):

You can use app.yaml to control [HTTP headers](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref#handlers_element) for static file handlers and not dynamic handlers. You would need to set the header within your app code.

Comment: This is backed up by the KB: "In order to add HTTP Strict-Transport-Security headers (HSTS) to your app, you must implement the headers within your app's code, not within your app's config file" - https://cloud.google.com/appengine/kb/

Comment: What is the difference between static and dynamic handler?

Answer (score 1):

I was looking over http headers in app.yaml today and saw this. It appears to be related to your issue.

> In addition, the header Strict-Transport-Security is removed from
>   responses served from any domains other than *.appspot.com.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/how-requests-are-handled#Python_Responses