# getting No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. GCP and Flask

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, cors, app.yaml

Hello i've developed an API with Python Flask on the Google App Engine and added the following:

```
#!flask/bin/python
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
from flask.ext.cors import CORS, cross_origin
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)
app.config['CORS_HEADERS'] = 'Content-Type'
@app.route('/companyInfoFull', methods=['GET'])
@cross_origin()
```

When trying to deploy a platform using my API I get the following:

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Thus, i've added the following to the following app.yaml file and now looks like this:

```
runtime: python
env: flex
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT main:app --timeout 220
runtime_config:
  python_version: 3.6
handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: main.py
  http_headers: 
    Access-Control-Allow-Origin: '*'
```

but i'm getting the following error when trying to compile from GCP:

```
An app.yaml (or appengine-web.xml) file is required to deploy this directory as an App Engine application. Create an app.yaml file using the directions at https://cloud.google
.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml (App Engine flexible environment) or https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref (App
 Engine standard environment) under the tab for your language.
```

Any ideas? Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The app.yaml must contains CPU, memory, network and disk resources, scaling, and other settings including environment variables. From looking at this error message your app.yaml appears to be missing those parameters. For more information please follow the
[Configuring your App with app.yaml](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml).

```
runtime: python
env: flex
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT main:app

runtime_config:
  python_version: 3

# This sample incurs costs to run on the App Engine flexible environment. 
# The settings below are to reduce costs during testing and are not appropriate
# for production use. For more information, see:
# https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml
manual_scaling:
  instances: 1
resources:
  cpu: 1
  memory_gb: 0.5
  disk_size_gb: 10
```

Comment: i'm now getting: Unexpected attribute "http_headers" for mapping type script.

Comment: There is a workaround https://github.com/riannucci/rietveldv2/issues/27

Comment: As [per](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45889266/11866104) you can use app.yaml to control HTTP headers for static file handlers not for the dynamic handlers.

Comment: Not sure. Is it static file or dynamic for my case? If it's dynamic, then what's the solution for me?

Comment: try this Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://your-url instead of '*'